# How to add a folder to my site with media or media browser?

Tags: 7, media

My site uses media browser and media browser plus and when you upload a file you get a drop down of where to upload files. Where can i go to add a directory to this drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a a list of vocabularies is being used to generate the drop down. In other words look at taxonomies and find out which one is being used and add a new term vocabulary